# AngularJS anonymous component replace inner scope

Tags: angularjs, angular, angularjs-scope, ecmascript-6

Hi I am using Angular with ES6, now I want to get rid of the `$scope` since Angular2 will not use it anymore and I want to create futureprove code,... this works:

```
let tab = this.tabManager.getArea.open({
        controller: ['$scope', function (scope) {

            console.log(scope);

            scope.close = function () {
                tab.close();
            }
        }],
        template: '<component-name on-close="close()" ...></component-name>'
    });
```

but how do I rewrite it without injecting the scope, I thought about something like this:

```
    let tab = this.tabManager.getArea.open({
        controller: [class {

            constructor() {
               console.log('construct');
            }


            close() {
                console.log('close');
                tab.close();
            }
        }],
        template: '<component-name on-close="close()" ...></component-name>'
    });
```

But it does not seem to work properly, the construtor is called up, however the **binding** for `on-close` does not seem to work.

Comment: The binding works but the scope no longer contains a `close` function. How can you access the controller in the template?

Comment: My controller of the component described in the template calls the onClose function which then should call the close function in the code shown above

Answer (score 0):

the controller class in 1.6 exposes $ctrl object , can access "close()" using that.try once

Comment: Tested it just in case it could work, but this will not work because the close function is a callback binding, which should be handled by the parent component and not by the components-controller itself